# Filter Array of objects on the basis of string value in ios

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I want to filter my array on the basis of string value but am not able to do so. Please help me to do this. Below is my array data.

Data Array:

> [["LocationCode": UP, "GSTN":, "CompanyCode": JVL, "SRNO": , "Description": Employees of Jubilant Ingrevia (other than SEZ units, Bharuch) who stay in hotel which is located in Uttar Pradhesh, "Company": Jubilant Ingrevia Limited, "Location": Uttar Pradesh, "Address": Bhartiagram, NH-24, Gajraula, Amroha - 244223], ["GSTN":, "CompanyCode": JVL, "Company": Jubilant Ingrevia Limited, "LocationCode": GJ, "Address": 133, Savli Jarod Road, Samlaya, Vadodara - 391520, "Description": Employees of Jubilant Ingrevia (other than SEZ units, Bharuch) who stay in hotel which is located in Gujarat, "Location": Gujarat, "SRNO": ], ["Address": Nira (R.S.), Village Nimbut, Tal. Baramati, Pune - 412102, "Company": Jubilant Ingrevia Limited, "Location": Maharashtra, "GSTN":, "Description": Employees of Jubilant Ingrevia (other than SEZ units, Bharuch) who stay in hotel which is located in Maharashtra, "SRNO": , "LocationCode": MH, "CompanyCode": JVL], ["Location": Telangana, "Address": 304 305, 3rd Floor, Doshi Chambers, Opp. United Insurance Building, Basheerbagh, Ranga Reddy, Hyderabad, Telangana - 500029, "Company": Jubilant Ingrevia Limited, "CompanyCode": JVL, "Description": Employees of Jubilant Ingrevia (other than SEZ units, Bharuch) who stay in hotel which is located in Telangana, "SRNO": , "LocationCode": TL, "GSTN":], ["Address": Plot 1A, Sector 16A, Institutional Area, Noida,Gautam Buddha Nagar, Uttar Pradesh, 201301, "Company": Jubilant Pharmova Limited, "Description": Employees of Jubilant Pharmova who stay in hotel which is located in Uttar Pradesh, "LocationCode": UP, "Location": Uttar Pradesh, "CompanyCode": JOL, "GSTN":, "SRNO": ]]

My Code for filter:

```
var mergedArray:[Dictionary<String,Any>] = []

for item in dataArray {
    
    if !mergedArray.contains(where: {($0["Company"] as! String) == items}) {
        //uniqueArray.append(item)
        var dict = item as! [String: Any]
       
        mergedArray.append(dict)
        
        dataArray = mergedArray
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: What's the value of `items`? Why do you use `Dictionary` and not a real ViewModel with custom structs?

Comment: Are you sure that your dictionaries are correctly formatted? The following key:value pair should have the value between quotes, to be considered a string: `"Company": Jubilant Ingrevia Limited`. It should actually be `"Company": "Jubilant Ingrevia Limited"`.

Comment: What is items ?

Comment: Try to write it with classic for loop to see what you must do then reduce syntax. Also use ‘?’ , do not unwrap.

Comment: @Ptit Xav items is a string value by using that I need to filter the data. If that string value exists in the dictionary then I need to show only that.

Comment: @KishanSingh: you can not modify dataArray while looping on it

Answer (score 0):

may be like this :

```
    for item in dataArray {
        
        if !mergedArray.contains(where: {($0["Company"] as! String) == items}) {
            //uniqueArray.append(item)
            let dict = item as [String: Any]
           
            mergedArray.append(dict)
            
        }
    }
    
    dataArray = mergedArray // moved dataArray outside loop
```